# Сборка open SCADA, ld file not recognized: File format not recognized

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, ld

собираю *openSCADA*, получаю следующую ошибку при `make`:

```
$ make 
...
making all in IEC61850
make[5]: Вход в каталог `/home/r2d2/SCADA/src/moduls/daq/IEC61850'
/bin/sh ../../../../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/QtCore   -g -O2  -module -avoid-version -no-undefined -Llibiec61850/build/src  -o daq_IEC61850.la -rpath /usr/lib64/openscada daq_IEC61850_la-iec61850_module.lo -liec61850
libtool: link: g++  -fPIC -DPIC -shared -nostdlib /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/crtbeginS.o  .libs/daq_IEC61850_la-iec61850_module.o   -Llibiec61850/build/src -liec61850 -L/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8 -L/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/lib -L/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../.. -lstdc++ -lm -lc -lgcc_s /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/crtendS.o /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../lib64/crtn.o  -O2   -Wl,-soname -Wl,daq_IEC61850.so -o .libs/daq_IEC61850.so
libiec61850/build/src/libiec61850.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[5]: *** [daq_IEC61850.la] Ошибка 1
make[5]: Выход из каталога `/home/r2d2/SCADA/src/moduls/daq/IEC61850'
make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Ошибка 1
make[4]: Выход из каталога `/home/r2d2/SCADA/src/moduls/daq'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Ошибка 1
make[3]: Выход из каталога `/home/r2d2/SCADA/src/moduls'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Ошибка 1
make[2]: Выход из каталога `/home/r2d2/SCADA/src'
make[1]: *** [all] Ошибка 2
make[1]: Выход из каталога `/home/r2d2/SCADA/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Ошибка 1
```

пошел на [сайт разработчиков стандарта](http://libiec61850.com/libiec61850/downloads/), там скачал исходники последней версии и установил:

```
$ make
$ sudo make INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local install
```

начал сбирать *openSCADA* снова, и получаю такую же ошибку.

может быть дело в другом? как исправить?

---

дополнительная информация:

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 3.82
Эта программа собрана для x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

uname -a
Linux %compname% 3.11.10-29-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 5 16:24:00 UTC 2015 (338c513) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

дистрибутив *OpenSuse 13.1*

Comment: так есть же готовые rpm-пакеты...
http://oscada.org/oscadaArch/0.8.0/SuSE/13/

Answer (score 2):

на просторах интернета беглым поиском найдена лишь [*статья на китайском*](http://blog.zhourunsheng.com/2013/08/libiec61850%e5%9c%a8openscada%e7%b3%bb%e7%bb%9f%e4%b8%ad%e7%9a%84%e4%bd%bf%e7%94%a8%e4%ba%8c/) про интеграцию *libiec61850* в *openscada*.

одна рекомендация: гугловский авто-переводчик вставляет пробелы там где надо и не надо, потому строки/команды лучше копировать из оригинала.